# Get array length from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Recently I started working on a project using Next JS and Firebase... I have added the data in the Cloud Firestore. I can get the details back from the firestore but not get the length of an array.
Here is the image of the data structure in firestore
[image]

I have tried this code

```
let len = 0
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then(snap => {
len = snap.data().disliked1.length
console.log(len)
})
```

But I get `undefined`

How do I get the length of this `disliked1` array length?

Comment: Can you `console.log(snap.data())` and share the value?

Comment: yea sure here it is.... but is for liked1 which is the same as that of disliked1: https://pastebin.com/Y5rKSZJQ

Comment: I can't see any field `disliked1`

Comment: it is same as the liked1 field in the console output... both are arrays

Comment: But I cannot confirm if that field is there in the received doc snapshot

Comment: it is there... both the liked1 and disliked1 are there in the console... but since I am not near my computer I have sent the previous version of the file... but both exists

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the ID is correct by logged it before and also if the snapshot received exists.

```js
let len = 0
console.log(user.id)
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then(snap => {
  if (snap.exists) {
    console.log(snap.data())
    len = snap.data().disliked1.length
  } else {
    console.log("Snapshot not found")
  }
  console.log(len)
})
```